# Автоматическое заполнение таблицы,при добавление записи в другу!

Tags: c#, sql-server

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите,возможно ли в mssql 2016 реализовать такую штучку,при добавление записей в одну таблицу,определенные поля отображались в другой таблице?Буду очень признательным за помощь,совет,ссылку.

Comment: @nzeemin,допустим есть 2 таблицы                                                   1)Журнал Прихода(Наименование детали,наименование Поставщика,цена детали,количество,сумма,дата поступления)                                                                                       2)Склад(материал,каоличество)                                                                            так вот,при добавлени записи в таблицу  "1", в таблице "2"  заполнялась материалом и его количеством.как то так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По всей видимости, вам нужно использовать триггер на INSERT:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189799(v=sql.120).aspx

**UPDATE** Но в такой формулировке

> допустим есть 2 таблицы 1)Журнал Прихода(Наименование
>   детали,наименование Поставщика,цена детали,количество,сумма,дата
>   поступления) 2)Склад(материал,каоличество) так вот,при добавлени
>   записи в таблицу "1", в таблице "2" заполнялась материалом и его
>   количеством.как то так

-- в таком варианте я бы лучше сделал INSERT два раза -- в таблицу Журнал Прихода и в таблицу Склад.
Причина в том что триггер на INSERT отрабатывает всегда. Допустим, вам понадобится импортировать записи в Журнал Прихода или вставлять тестовые -- триггер всё равно отработает.

Comment: а тригеры нужно как ни будь подключать к visualStudio C#,типа как хранимую процедуру,или нет?